# Docker: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker

Have two running docker containers, Bob and Alice, listening.  When running a third process, Jim, who talks to both Bob and Alice.  When running this command:

```
docker run --net home_default --link alice --link bob  -e BOB_URI=http://bob:8080/v3 -e ALICE_URI=http://alice:8080/v1 talker
```

I see logs on the bob server:

```
http: panic serving 172.18.0.7:35762: write tcp 172.18.0.5:8080->172.18.0.7:35762: write: connection reset by peer
```

Am I not setting up the links correctly?  Can the servers not talk back to the running process

Answer (score 1):

[You don't need to use links on a custom network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/links) as the custom network provides all the functionality that `--link` does for the default docker0 network.

When using links on a custom network, they perform a [slightly different role of setting up and alias](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-without-using-user-defined-networks).

```
docker run --net home_default --name bob -d alpine sleep 60
docker run --net home_default alpine ping -c 4 bob
docker run --net home_default --link bob:bob1 alpine ping -c 4 bob1

docker run --net home_default --name alice -d alpine sleep 60
docker run --net home_default alpine ping -c 4 alice
docker run --net home_default --link alice:alica1 alpine ping -c 4 alice1
```

I would say the issue lies in your service rather than the Docker setup.

Comment: Service works fine stand alone.  Noticed it still behaves the same way when not linked.

Comment: Interesting... Is `home_default` a standard docker brdige network? Bridge networks are a standard linux bridge with some virtual interfaces attached so wouldn't expect too many issues with them. Might be more likely if you are using an overlay network or one of the other drivers.

Comment: It's setup as bridge.